# Como mostrar los datos obtenidos de una API JSON Abierta

Tags: php, html, json, api, curl

Estoy experimentando en JSON con una API abierta y PHP. Lo que necesito es mostrar los datos específicos de las farmacias de turno para cierta "comuna". ¿Alguna idea de como continuar?

```
<?php

$apiUrl = 'https://farmanet.minsal.cl/index.php/ws/getLocalesTurnos';
//Es necesario tener habilitada la directiva allow_url_fopen para usar file_get_contents
if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
    $json = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
} else {
    //De otra forma utilizamos cURL
    $curl = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}

$farmacia = json_decode($json)
// Hasta aquí llego 

?>
```

Este es el formato de los datos en el JSON

```
[
{   "fecha":"2022-11-22",
    "local_id":"1",
    "fk_region":"6",
    "fk_comuna":"69",
    "fk_localidad":"32",
    "local_nombre":"CRUZ VERDE ",
    "comuna_nombre":"QUILLOTA",
    "localidad_nombre":"QUILLOTA",
    "local_direccion":"OHIGGINS 195, LOCAL 1",
    "funcionamiento_hora_apertura":"09:00:00",
    "funcionamiento_hora_cierre":"08:59:00",
    "local_telefono":"+5633332269467",
    "local_lat":"-32.8793428949969",
    "local_lng":"-71.2467871500868",
    "funcionamiento_dia":"martes"
}, 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar los datos en un JSON mediante PHP y luego leerlos a través de JQUERY.

```
<?
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
   
$consulta = file_get_html('https://farmanet.minsal.cl/index.php/ws/getLocalesTurnos');

$nombreArchivo = "demo.json";
$archivo = fopen($nombreArchivo, "w");
fwrite($archivo, $consulta);
fclose($archivo);
 
?>

 <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           
            
               $.ajax({
                    url: "demo.json",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);                       
                            $('#demo').append('<div class="name">'+json[0].fk_localidad+'</>');
                    }
                });
         
               
         });
      </script>
      
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

Librería necesaria:
[simple_html_dom.php](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/1.5/)

Comment: Puedes obtener los datos segun su posición y etiqueta:

Ejemplo:
Posición 5 - etiqueta local_id

json[4].local_id